# AEM 6.5: Is there an HTL way to output Webpack-generated CSS within <style> tags from an AEM clientlib category?

Tags: css, webpack, aem, inline-styles, client-library

**Goal:**
I have a specific clientlib ready with "critical CSS" that I would like to add to a page template in `<style>` tags, per [Google's performance recommendations](https://web.dev/extract-critical-css/) on a high-traffic e-Commerce site.

**Problem:**
We all know how to add a file reference in HTL:

```
<sly data-sly-use.clientlib="/libs/granite/sightly/templates/clientlib.html" data-sly-call="${clientlib.css @ categories='template.noncritical'}"/>
```

but how would I output plain generated CSS styles on the page via HTL? Is there some other HTL property I could use?
I want this:

```
<style>
  /* contents of AEM clientlib CSS here */
</style>
```

**Tried:**
I have Googled, searched StackOverflow, and looked in the [AEM docs about clientlibs](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-65/developing/introduction/clientlibs.html?lang=en), but haven't found anything about inlining styles, except to

- use a third-party script to inline critical CSS. (don't want to do)
- modify HTML Library Manager OSGi configuration to inline all styles by default (don't want to do)

I am looking for something AEM-native that can be turned "on" or "off" in HTL. Thanks for reading and offering any solutions you may have.

Comment: AFAIK there isn't an OOB way to do it. If your webpack generated is in a file you just can't inline embed the file's contents using HTL. You don't need a 3rd party script to do it, but you would need to implement a Sling model or a WCM Use script which will read the file contents and expose it as via a field/variable which can then be used to embed it on to the page. However, you may have to use the `unsafe` context to get it working fine and that may expose security issues if you don't have complete control over the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can try https://github.com/dmantsevich/aem-critical-css

It will generate CSS files and "integrate" with AEM. You can use it for extract small component CSS.
Some features:

1. CSS will be loaded only, if component presents on the page
2. Supports 2 injection types: `<style />` and `<link />`
3. Supports **less, css, scss.**
4. CSS will be injected only once

#### Example:

*MyComponentTemplate.html*

```
<sly data-sly-use.aemCriticalCSS="${'./_aem-critical-css.js'}"
@aem-critical-css="my-component/my-component.scss">${aemCriticalCSS.inject @ context="unsafe"}</sly>
```

Where **my-component/my-component.scss** is a path to css (related to **ui.frontend/src/** folder). We used it on several projects and it helps to improve rendering performance. (path can be configured)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Core Components functionality https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-core-components/using/developing/including-clientlibs.html?lang=en#inlining

```html
<style type="text/css"
    data-sly-use.clientlibs="${'com.adobe.cq.wcm.core.components.models.ClientLibraries' @ categories='wknd.base'}">
    ${clientlibs.cssInline @ context="unsafe"}
</style>
```